# Regex, excluding non-number

Tags: java, regex

In my program I read input from the console and determine whether it is a number or not. `Numbers can be any decimal +-`. For instance having 123.18p18 is not allowed since there is a nondigit in there, same with -123.18p18. The bad way of doing this (which I am currently doing)  is checking if it is a double and catching exceptions, but since I am just parsing a string I think regex is far better to use here. This is my first day in its use (regex) and it seems like an alien language.

I came up with `".*\\D+.*"` but that only handles positive numbers.

Edit: Integers are also acceptable.

Comment: I assume scientific notation is not required?  For example, 1.2e3.  Will affect the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for:

```
"^[+-]?\\d+([.]\\d+)?$"
```

Optional plus or minus in the beginning, followed by at least one digit. Before the end of the string there can optionally be one dot followed by at least one digit.

Comment: @ring0: Won't match. It is easy to implement it to match it also. IMHO, a user shouldn't enter `.123`, he should enter `0.123` in order to make sure the leading dot is not a typo.

Comment: @user948652: Yes, like in my description: if there is a dot, there must be at least one more digit. IMHO `2.` is not a number, whereas `2.0` is one. Feel free to change it to your needs ;)

Comment: Habit of punctuating sentences ruined that comment, I meant "2" is not accepted while "2.0" is.

Comment: @user948652: This definitely matches `"2"`. Are you sure there is no whitespace involved? Try printing your input in quotation marks, you'll see leading or trailing whitespace, which you can `trim()` away.

Answer (score 2):

To solve your initial problem, you can use the [java.util.Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class. It provides methods for testing whether the next input is an integer, double, etc., or even testing whether the next input conforms to a given regular expression.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
//...
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

while ( s.hasNext() ) {
    if ( s.hasNextInt() ) {
        int i = s.readInt();
        // Some work.
    } else if ( s.hasNextDouble() ) {
        double d = s.nextDouble();
        // Some work.
    } else if ( s.hasNext(regex) ) {
        String t = s.next(regex);
        // Some work.
    }
    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following regex might work for you;

It defines a pattern which starts with either a + or - followed by zero or more digits and if there is a decimal point, then it must be followed by at least one digit

```
"^[+-]?\\d+(?:\\.?\\d+)$"
```

Comment: The unescaped dot will match any character.

Comment: You have to escape it with double backslash, or else it won't compile due to the invalid escape sequence.

Comment: Why the non-capturing group?

Comment: Now all you have to do is fix your quantifiers. ATM you will also match `"-."`

Comment: @jlordo Double slashes in Java make me cry; Thanks :)

Comment: @AlanFoster: Your solution on the top will now match `"1."`. If that is a correct number in your opinion, then we are done ;)

Comment: @jlordo Haha, yeah. I just got rid of the first one entirely now. :)

Comment: @AlanFoster: As Tim Pietzcker already asked, why are you using a non-capturing group?

Answer (score 0):

Try `double doubleInstance = Double.parseDouble(string);` and proceed...

Comment: try/catch is an exercise left up to the reader, should have indicated that. Thanks though!

Comment: It says in the question, that OP is already doing that. He is looking specifically for a regex solution.